# Distribution of the ratio of two generalized gamma distribution with same location parameters?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, gamma-distribution

X $\sim$ GG(p,d,$\theta_{1}$,$\mu$) where p is power, d is shape, $\theta_1$ is scale and $\mu$ is location parameter. Also Consider Y $\sim$ GG(p,d,$\theta_{2}$,$\mu$) where p is power, d is shape, $\theta_2$ is scale and $\mu$ is location parameter.

What is the distribution of $\;Z=\frac{X}{Y}$?

All the papers I read so far only have the case without location parameter. Please help.
Thanks

Comment: It seems like a matter of [computation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution). Have you tried anything? You can try something in the meantime.

Comment: @probablyme .I did try few things such as using transformation by setting $Y = U_1$ and $X = U_1*U_2$ and find the Jacobian and etc. but I end up with complicated form. If I don't have location parameters it will be beta prime distribution. http://threeplusone.com/FieldGuide.pdf If you check the Generalized Beta Prime distribution in the pdf, I wonder if it gave me answer!!

Comment: I don't know about transformations. Are they independent? Also, when you post a reference, please specify where your issue is. The pdf you gave is 180 pages.

Comment: @probablyme. Sorry, It is on page 108. Generalized Beta Prime distribution. In parenthesis it mentioned generalize gamma ratio. and Yes they are independent.

Comment: What is the density of the $GG$? The parameters are not enough as notation is not universal.

Comment: @probablyme. It is $f(x;\theta_1,d,p,\mu) = (\frac{p}{\theta_1^d})(x-\mu)^{d-1}e^{-[(x-\mu)/\theta_1]^p}/\Gamma(d/p)$.Thank you for your time. I appreciate your help

Comment: Well, I haven't tried yet. I might not be able to do it. But I will still try, I have some free time :)

Comment: Wait, do you want the pdf or the _name_ of the distribution? You want the pdf right? I will have no clue about the name.

Comment: @probablyme.  Pdf would be great. I may be able to find the name if it has familiar form. :)

Comment: Ok, yeah, I knew it would be horrible. But  I am not familiar with all the distributions on that page. It is possible that using one of the density functions in your pdf file, the integral could be made really simple by making into another density function that is in your pdf with some substitution or other minor adjustment. Or you might be able to turn it into the expectation of one of those distributions. That would be my strategy. Or there might be a calculus trick, but I don't want to think about it too long.